# Allow double slash in path - ui-router

Tags: angular-ui-router

I want to allow ui-router to resolve a state with doubleslashes in the path.

I have the following state:

```
.state('state', {
  url: 'path/to//:foo',
  templateUrl: 'template.html',
})
```

If I call `$state.go('state', {foo: 'bar'})`, the state resolves to `example.com/path/to//bar`.

If I enter `example.com/path/to//bar` directly into the addressbar of the browser, then I get redirected to `example.com`.

Is there a way to allow doubleslashes in a route?